# Postgresql Array in Where Clause

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to filter with an array clause with just one row per "date (t1.starttime)". The current return creates a row for each item in the array. Is this possible? I have tried selecting distinct on t1.starttime but that is only returning results from the first t3.store.

```
SELECT
t2.name,
date (t1.starttime),
Count(t1.starttime) as "# Plays",
Count(distinct(t1.playerid)) as "# Stores"

FROM
public.billing t1 JOIN public.medias t2 on t1.mediaitemid = t2.id 
JOIN public.players t3 on t1.playerid = t3.id 

WHERE
t3.store in  ('0038','3285') and
t2.name LIKE any (array['COMM_7032%']) and
t1.starttime >= date('2017-04-26') and 
t1.starttime < date('2017-05-01') and
t1.channelname = 'myNetwork'

GROUP BY
date (t1.starttime),
t2.name,
t1.playerid,

ORDER BY
date (t1.starttime)

Returned Data...
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-27";20;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-27";20;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-28";34;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-28";34;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-29";35;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-29";35;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-30";21;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-30";22;1
```

Trying to combine the dates so it reads this...

```
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-27";40;2 
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-28";68;2 
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-29";70;2 
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-30";43;2
```

Comment: Hi @KevMoe can you add some sample data (no need to be real)  of what you have and from that sample what should be returned? It would help Us to help you much better.

Comment: I have added the return... I would prefer it combine the two date rows... for example it should read...  

"COMM_7032";"2017-04-27";40;2
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-28";68;2
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-29";70;2
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-30";43;2

Comment: Try to remove t1.playerid

Comment: Thanks Roman, but that did not make a difference.